# Apple Mach-O Linker Warning - Framework Search Paths?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've stumbled upon an annoying error: Apple Mach-O Linker Warning.

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/erik/Documents/Xcode/Hello'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FFriend'.

My Project folder is called "Hello Friend".
In my Framework Search Paths it has 4 rows showing:

- $(inherited)
- /Users/erik/Documents/Xcode/Hello
- Friend
- $(PROJECT_DIR)

It looks like it has divided the word "Hello Friend" into two sections because of the space between the words so I'm thinking that's the explanation?

I've tried to edit it to

- $(inherited)
- /Users/erik/Documents/Xcode/Hello Friend
- $(PROJECT_DIR)

but it jumps back.

Any ideas?

Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to solve it. Easy fix. For other stumbling upon this problem just edit the Framework Search Paths and add quotation marks to words with space.

I.e:
/Users/erik/Documents/Xcode/"Hello Friend"

Comment: Where do I find that text to fix?

Comment: For me the path that caused the warning was in Target>Build Settings>Search Paths>Library Search Paths.

Comment: escape spaces using \     single or double quotation mark does not work, xcode interprets them as separate paths

Answer (score 22):

1: Open your Projects

2: Click on Targets

3: Click on Build Settings

4: Click on "Framework Search Paths" or "Library Search Paths" and you should find the bogus paths listed in there, which you can delete.

[image]

Comment: Clearing Library Search Paths did the trick for me. Thanks much!

Comment: remove all path and add framework again ... hopefully this action work for you.