# Xcode 7 Library search path warning

Tags: xcode, xcode7

This is the warning that it is showing:

> directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks' "

Can anyone help resolve the warning?

Comment: This answer fixed this error to me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665196/ld-file-not-found-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invoca

Comment: @arwaz shaikh Do not forget to mark my answer as the right answer (if you think that it rightly answers to your question), it could help people to find it more quickly via Google or Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [‘ld: warning: directory not found for option’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

### This is how I fixed this problem

Further to a migration of my Xcode project, from Xcode 6.4 to Xcode 7, I get the warning message below (after compilation) for the **Test target** :

```
directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
```

Actually I found something when comparing a new project vs an older one...

In the old project, the warning was only being produced by the **test target** of my projects.  Under **'Search Paths'**, I found it was including two items under **'Framework Search Paths'**:

```
$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks
$(inherited)
```

The new project kept the **'Framework Search Paths'** empty.

**Deleting those entries in my older project then removed the warning.**

Notes:

I have not exhaustively compared settings, so there may be additional differences.

**Also, just in case if one day you re-encounter one of the two following warning messages**, just remember that you will have to do that: if the warning is for option `'-L/...'` that is Library Search Paths, delete the stuff there. However if the warning is for option `'-F/...'` that is Framework Search Paths, delete the stuff there.

Comment: The above is correct. However, if you use CocoaPods, I found that it's also possible for the entry to reside in the *.xcconfig files it creates. Solution is identical: remove it, in this case from the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS line in your *.xcconfig file(s).

Comment: I have the exact same problem (-F/...) and I already deleted the stuff in Framework Search Paths, but the warning is still showing up.

Comment: Clean and re-build the Xcode project and the warning message should disappear.

Comment: I wasn't using the test target and ended up having to delete it to get it to build.

Comment: King-Wizard has the correct answer however more specifically you have to go into your project's 'Build Settings' > 'Search Paths' > 'Framework Search Paths'

Answer (score 19):

Based on the error message, it sounds like the first order of business is to get the target's path straightened out. You can edit the paths as shown in the answers to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999713/apple-mach-o-linker-warning-framework-search-paths). Be sure to check the path for all your targets if you're not sure which is generating the error --- this threw me for a bit after upgrading a project to the Xcode 7 beta; there was a path in the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS for the test target that needed to be deleted. The path that was in there was exactly the path you report getting the warning on; removing the path eliminated it.

Answer (score 16):

[King-Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1110914/king-wizard) is essentially correct, to elaborate a little more -

Xcode 7 is looking for your testing framework `XCtest.framework` in a path that does not exist. The path set by `$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks` under 'Search Paths -> Framework Search Paths'   is looking for the framework in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks` which is not a valid path. You can delete the line `$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks` to remove the error and still be able to run tests.

The correct path to 'XCTest.framework' is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks` for those that are curious.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error with Xcode 9.2 and here is my solutions without doing by hand:

1. Click on your project in Project Navigator
2. Go to targets and click on **MyProjectNameTest**
3. Click on Build Settings and Search for “**Framework Search Paths**”
4. Under **Framework Search Paths**, delete the paths and keep the “$(inherited)”.

[image]

For those of you that have the following error:

> directory not found for option ‘-L/…

that means it’s a Library Error, so you can try follow the below steps:

1. Click on your project (targets)
2. Click on Build Settings, Search for “Library Search Paths”
3. Under Library Search Paths, delete the paths and keep the “$(inherited)”