# Xcode 7: Linker warning for -F/<path> but no settings in app.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj match <path>

Tags: ios, xcode

I converted a Swift 1.x project for iOS to Swift 2.x using Xcode 7 beta 3.  It compiles and runs but I have a linker warning persisting.  I've done a search through the project.pbxprox for the offending path, and have looked in the "build settings" in Xcode but no sign of the offending path (not even in the Library Search Path or the Framework Search Path).  I did, however, find that the xcuser state file contains the substring.

The warning: `'ld: warning: directory not found for option "-F/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks\"'`

The searches:

```
[foo@bar baz{Swift2}]$ grep -r Baz.xcodeproj/ iPhoneOS9.0
grep: iPhoneOS9.0: No such file or directory
[foo@bar baz{Swift2}]$ grep -r 'Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks' Baz.xcodeproj/
Binary file Baz.xcodeproj//project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/bar.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate matches
[foo@bar baz{Swift2}]$
```

As usual, I've done a "clean" on both the project as well as the simulators (watch, iPhone).

I've examined the directory path and see that indeed there is no such path; the path components exist up to the 'iPhoneOS9.0.sdk' component.  That is, this path exists: `'/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk'` but there is no `'Developer'` subdirectory at that location.  There is, however, a framework directory underneath, but it's at `'iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/'` instead of `'iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'`.

Comment: Does this app itself contain any framework targets?

Comment: The only targets are <app> and <app>Tests, the default for a very simple, single view application (more of a tutorial/experiment than an app).

Comment: Try deleting the tests. - By this I mean the test _target._

Comment: Thanks, Matt, that worked.  Did this happen to you, too?  If you put up an answer, I'll accept it ;-)  Do you have any idea why this occurs?

Comment: No more binary match in the UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate file anymore, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this same issue. I believe that it happens because of some path incorrectly hard-coded into the test target's build settings. I don't know what path it is; my response is to **delete the test target**, and then the error goes away.

You can always make a new test target, and you don't have to delete the test *files*, so it's no great loss.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31368523/341994 says it's the Library Search Path or the Framework Search Path that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this issue after upgrading Xcode, then just in Xcode click;

File -> Open Recent -> Clear Menu.

Xcode -> Quite Xcode

Go to your project directory and open your project normally.

click cmd + alt + shift + K, this will clean your project

clcik cmd + B

Then you should be fine.

Comment: this clean my warning and add a new one -  " ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'

Comment: Roei, I had the same issue.  This post solved that problem for me though.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620919/4048853

Answer (score 0):

Change framework search path to $(PROJECT_DIR)/* for your test target