# 'directory not found' warning since Xcode 7 beta

Tags: xcode, swift

Since opening my older project (started in Xcode 3) in Xcode 7 I get the warning as shown in the screenshot below.
I have changed the deployment target from 8.3 to 9.0 to get rid of some compiler errors but this warning existed before and after.
I did try using Product/Clean, delete the DerivedData folder and re-installing Xcode, but the warning persists.
How do I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Just delete the test target (if you know how to do that).

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry for the duplicate question, it somehow didn't appear in the search. For anyone wondering, I've deleted the test target by following the instructions in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324163/xcode-how-to-delete-target-in-xcode-6-1 If the tab containing 'Projects' and 'Targets' doesn't show up, collapse it by pressing the icon just above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning says everything, Directory not found, Xcode is trying to get your framework from your old system.

Just go to Build Phases and search for "Framework" OR "iPhoneSimulator" (anything from the warning message). This will show you some search result, just delete that path.

If this didn't work, do this:

You need to do this:

1. Click on your project (targets)
2. Click on Build Settings
3. Under Library Search Paths (or under Frameworks Search Path), delete the path.

Comment: Thanks for the help, for some reason I only have the options 'info' and 'build settings' in my project in Xcode 7. The usual 'Build Phases' or 'General' tabs are nowhere to be seen... EDIT: Also, under Build Settings there is only a "Search Paths' option, but it doesn't provide any paths.

Comment: Make sure you have selected the correct target.
Seems like you have selected the `test` target.