# Compiler warning after install Xcode 7 Directory not found for option '-F ...'

Tags: xcode, compilation, xcode7

I check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368464/directory-not-found-warning-since-xcode-7-beta) with no success. 
Maybe sounds obvious but I look for inside the path and effectively does not exist the path, but this path is used for Xcode and not for my code (at least not that I know it)

[image]

The folder suppose to be here the but it does not exist (create the folder manually but does not fix it)
[image]

Somebody have an idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, here's how I solved it:

Go to the "Build Settings" of the Tests Targets (Make sure it's the "Tests" files with the white building block logo) and erase the Framework Search Paths.

Since you claim that the path doesn't exist, I suppose you were looking under the normal file instead of the "Tests". At least that was my mistake.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

I changed the last "Developer" in the Tests target's "Frameworks Search paths" path to "System" (...`iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`) because there *is* a `System/Library/Frameworks` directory. My code builds and the warning goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Ups !!

I have the problem in the Test Compiling.

[image]

I delete the path and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I can temporarily rectify the issue by selecting "Product - Clean" from the menu. It soon returns though.