# warning: directory not found for option after update to xcode 7

Tags: xcode, swift

I have totally no idea about what does it mean:
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 7 Beta Library search path warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827022/xcode-7-beta-library-search-path-warning)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For me it ended up being in the TestTarget Build Settings.

1. Go to **Build Settings**
2. Click the up/down arrows next to your project name (above the Basic/All buttons) to select your Test Target
3. In the search bar, type in **Search Paths**
4. Delete any conflicting paths under the **Framework Search Paths** or **Library Search Paths**
5. Clean
6. Build

In my case, I had a path under **Framework Search Paths** pointing at **Developer/Library/Frameworks**

Answer (score 4):

Go to Project Settings, and delete/remove excess framework paths that you don't need.

or
Click on projects
CLick on build settings and then under library search paths, delete the paths.

**UPDATE:**

if you cannot find it, then click on 'Find', then 'Find in Project', search 'path', you may then get the result, from there select framework search paths. you will see framework search paths. I hope this helps.

Comment: I had nothing in framework path either.  When I checked framework path for my project's tests, that's where I did have a framework path.  I removed that, cleaned and built, and the error is now gone.

Answer (score 1):

I meet a same problem.And I resolve it by https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3729

You can click on testsTarget and click build settings and open the Framework Search Paths to remove the warning Path.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I was using Carthage to implement the Pod. The problem I was having is that I had not yet installed Carthage on my machine and it was necessary to give Build

```
$ brew install carthage
$ carthage build
```

Answer (score -1):

What is working for me is:

1. Go to ' General '  in Xcode and click 'Embedded Binaries'
2. Add the .dylib and .a file to your project
3. Lastly, goto 'Build Settings' search for 'Other Linker Flags' ,then copy your library commad line argument and add it there.