# Swift - Directory not found for option

Tags: swift

So I'm getting this warning "ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'"

Now I've gone to my project build settings and checked the Framework and Library search paths and they are both empty. The only way I was able to get rid of it is if I deleted "View Controller based status bar" but I need it to be gone so I have to leave it in.

Is there another way to get rid of this message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning when I update to xcode 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630967/warning-when-i-update-to-xcode-7)

Comment: But I tried deleting the paths of most answers have said but my project doesn't have any to delete. And I still get the warning.

Comment: Try looking under Test Targets as I recommend here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32658881/1108806