# Swift 2 iOS 9 - ld: warning: directory not found iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks

Tags: xcode, swift2, ios9

I have a warning in my ios appTests:

```
Ld /Users/Mazorati/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/exchangerate-fxnywlxmtfpaccbcpsmygvhirtma/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/exchangerateTests.xctest/exchangerateTests normal x86_64
cd /Users/Mazorati/Projects/iOS/exchangerate
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk -L/Users/Mazorati/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/exchangerate-fxnywlxmtfpaccbcpsmygvhirtma/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Mazorati/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/exchangerate-fxnywlxmtfpaccbcpsmygvhirtma/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/Mazorati/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/exchangerate-fxnywlxmtfpaccbcpsmygvhirtma/Build/Intermediates/exchangerate.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/exchangerateTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/exchangerateTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -bundle_loader /Users/Mazorati/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/exchangerate-fxnywlxmtfpaccbcpsmygvhirtma/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/exchangerate.app/exchangerate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework XCTest -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Mazorati/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/exchangerate-fxnywlxmtfpaccbcpsmygvhirtma/Build/Intermediates/exchangerate.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/exchangerateTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/exchangerateTests.swiftmodule -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Mazorati/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/exchangerate-fxnywlxmtfpaccbcpsmygvhirtma/Build/Intermediates/exchangerate.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/exchangerateTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/exchangerateTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Mazorati/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/exchangerate-fxnywlxmtfpaccbcpsmygvhirtma/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/exchangerateTests.xctest/exchangerateTests
```

Error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 7 Beta Library search path warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827022/xcode-7-beta-library-search-path-warning)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. Click on your project (targets)
2. Click on Build Settings
3. Use the arrows next to your project name (right above the Basic and All buttons) the change to the Tests target
4. if the warning is ...for option '-L/... thats Library Search Paths, delete the stuff there
   if the warning is ...for option '-F/... thats Framework Search Paths, delete the stuff there
5. Clean
6. Build

Comment: please update the answer to include the information in the link.

Comment: All my pods got erased, and it can't find any of my other frameworks now. kinda made the problem worse.

Comment: Because it's a hack, not a solution. Did you manually create a unit test class. If you did, check the target. It might not be attached to the main project.

Answer (score 5):

The warning i was getting was this:

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'

My Framework Search Paths were empty so updating/deleting this + Clean + Rebuild did not work for me...

If you are in this situation, **try deleting your projects test target**.

Comment: Well, that did actually work ... not the best solution though i guess.

Comment: In test target

if the warning is ...for option '-L/... thats Library Search Paths, delete the stuff there
if the warning is ...for option '-F/... thats Framework Search Paths, delete the stuff there

Answer (score 1):

I got this warning together with 44 errors about about classes not valid for i386. What helped for me was:

- product clean
- close Xcode
- remove all files from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Answer (score 0):

I receive this error when opening files from their destination in finder. However, if I open the project from X Code it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Project 'Test' file delete to solution this app.