# Xcode 7 Warning - directory not found for option - iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I have got this warning when upgrade my project:

> directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'

How can I fix this issue?

I have cleaned the project but the warning still occurs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 7 Beta Library search path warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827022/xcode-7-beta-library-search-path-warning)

Answer (score 19):

I recently upgraded my project as well and ran into the same thing. This fixed it for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32620919/3279011

Note that you need to edit the properties of the test-project, not your main one (that's what took me a while to process).

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on your project (targets)
2. Click onn Build Settings
3. Use the arrows next to your project name (right above the Basic and All buttons) the change to the Tests target
4. if the warning is ...for option '-F/... thats Framework Search Paths, delete the stuff there
5. Clean
6. Build
   Go for it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with Xcode 9.2 and here is my solution:

1. Click on your project (targets)
2. Click on Build Settings, Search for “Framework Search Paths”
3. Under Framework Search Paths, delete the paths and keep the “$(inherited)”.
4. This might happen when you move the referenced file around.

This is what the screen looked like before deleting

[image]