# How do I resolve "directory not found for option" when installing quick and nimble?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I get the following warnings when I install quick and nimble in xcode 7

> Directory not found for option
>   '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
>
> Directory not found for option
>   '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'

There was an [issue](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble/issues/166) open on this, but it seems like it was resolved, so I am guessing I am doing something else wrong.

There is also this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684130/xcode-7-warning-directory-not-found-for-option-iphonesimulator9-0-sdk) but the answers there suggest removing the framework search path,  which I have something for google maps added to that and I get other errors when I delete that entry.

Any other ideas?

Here is my podfile:

```
platform :ios  , '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'OurLatitude' do
  pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 0.9'
  pod 'DateTools'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
  pod 'SDWebImage/MapKit', '~>3.7'
end


target 'OurLatitudeTests' do
  pod 'Quick', '~> 0.6.0'
  pod 'Nimble', '2.0.0-rc.3'
  pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 0.9'
  pod 'DateTools'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
  pod 'SDWebImage/MapKit', '~>3.7'
end
```

Comment: This error message 90% most likely actually won't impact anything.

Comment: I agree, i just don't like seeing the little yellow triangle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue has been resolved only very recently and hasn't made it into a release yet. I guess we'll just have to patient :)

Comment: I guess I should have looked closer at the comments in the issue.  If I point to master on nimble the warning goes away,  I think the issue is still open on quick and it has not been resolved for quick yet (I still get the warning when I point to the swift-2.0 or master branch for quick)