# Quickblox: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, quickblox

I used following pods but I'm getting Error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> **platform :ios, "8.0" use_frameworks!**

```
target 'CSocial' do

#
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'

pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

pod 'FBSDKShareKit'

pod 'FlickrKit'

pod 'MONActivityIndicatorView'
```

## Chat Integration

```
pod 'QuickBlox'
#Production pod
#pod 'QMCVDevelopment', :git => 'git@github.com:QuickBlox/QMChatViewController-ios.git', :commit => '7244eaf609797a5dc5ec6d28dc2b284633b03a1f'

#For development pods
pod 'QMCVDevelopment', :git => 'https://github.com/QuickBlox/QMChatViewController-ios.git'

#Production pod
#pod 'QMServicesDevelopment', :git => 'git@github.com:QuickBlox/q-municate-services-ios.git', :commit => 'ab56ac143bb770e76409a027bfb38de582d728aa'

#For development pods
pod 'QMServicesDevelopment', :git => 'https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-services-ios.git'
```

end

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 7 Library search path warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827022/xcode-7-library-search-path-warning)

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below steps and your problem will be solved:

1) Tap on "Pods.xcodeproj" in your project

2) Select all the pods / any of one in which you are facing the issue.

3)Tap on "Build Settings" and change "Build Active Architecture Only" to "NO"

4) Now try to build to build the project and your problem will be solved.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swift you have to link these libraries in the build settings of the project 
search for the Framework search path and add the path for the libraries

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have added all the frameworks mentioned by the Quickblox website ,

Add -lxml2, -ObjC flags to Other Linker Flags section in project settings

[Official doc link](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework) including bolts if it's not already added by pods

For QMCV and QMService i am also facing some issue recently but after some setting is worked